# ASP.Net Web Service returns no data after deployment

Tags: asp.net, web-services, deployment, iis-7, web

```
Visual Studio 2010
.Net framework 4.0
IIS 7.0
Windows Server 2008
```

> ```
> within a visual studio solution I have: 
>
> - Website project 
> - Webservice project
> ```

Basically, Website function calls webservice methods to SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE data.

```
This works fine when I try to run through the visual studio, but does not work on the server. 
 - using Visual Studio 2010 express on the server, the solution compiles successfully and gets the requested data. 
 - however, if I try to retrieve some data from deployed web service like:
 http://localhost/LTC_webservice/LTCWebService.asmx/GetWorkTypes
```

I get no tables..
so my website gets this page:

Cannot find table 0.

```
IIS Settings: 
- using ASP.Net v4.0 application pool 
- Managed Pipeline = Classic
- ISAPI and CGI Restrictions: allowed on ASP.NET v4.0.30319
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: cannot find table[0] so its probably a database call returning dataset and you are trying yo access first datatable which is not available. check your connection string? or data you are assuming is not there... do you have any logs and please provide some code so people can actually help.

Comment: it was connection string issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database connection should be SQL authentication, not windows authentication. 
My connection string was connecting to the database using the windows authentication, not the SQL authentication with user id and password.